# session destroy problem after redirect back from payment gateway in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-5, session-state

I am using an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I have a problem with session being destroyed after redirect back from payment gateway.

> It is conference system. i am using this every year for 3 month only till last year no such issue occur when i am using it now **i got that issue specially with Mozilla and google chrome but In Microsoft Edge not facing such session out problem**

This is my Session-related code:

```
ConferenceSession profileData = new ConferenceSession
                {
                    username = log.emailID,
                    cid = log.confid
                };
Session["TstConfSESSION"] = profileData;
```

Filter :

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["TstConfSESSION"] == null)
        {
            //filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("RedirectReason", "Session destroyed - try again!");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Response controller

```
[CustomFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult payment(string id, FormCollection frm)
{ 
    // payment gateway response code 
}
```

I added these settings in `web.config` to increase session time:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Increase session time for payment gateway -->
    <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```